# Regex to disallow certain characters in specific sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regular expression that allows only letters, numbers, spaces or hyphens. However, I'd like to disallow the user to do the following:

```
hello--world Have more than one hyphen sitting next to each other
--hello Have a hyphen in the beginning. It must have a number or letter first
```

How do I accomplish this? My current regex looks like this:

```
let alphanumericTest = new RegExp("^\s*([0-9a-zA-Z- ]*)\s*$");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this regex expression. `^\s*[0-9a-zA-Z](?:(?!--)[0-9a-zA-Z- ])*$`

[This is a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/P6dVNs/3)

Answer (score 1):

You could make you match a bit more efficient without using a negative lookahead for matching non consecutive hyphens using repeating groups which can optionally start with an hyphen after the first word.

```
^[ ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*-?(?:[ ]+-?(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+-?)*)*$
```

(Used `[ ]` to match a space for clarity)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[ ]*` Match 0+ spaces
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:-[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a hyphen and 1+ what is listed
- `-?` Match optional hyphen
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[ ]+-?(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+-?)*` Match 1+ spaces, optional hyphen, repeat 0+ times what is listed and optional hyphen
- `)*` Close outer non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nXU10z/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`let alphanumericTest = new RegExp("^(?!-)(?!.*--)[0-9a-zA-Z- ]+(?<!-)$");`

This checks that the first character is not a `-` and that there are no consecutive `--`s anywhere in the string